# HTML Parsing w/ BS4: couldn't find a tree builder...'html parser'

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble understanding how to proceed after receiving an error in my pydev console.

the console is returning the following:

```
  b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <title>A simple example page</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <p>Here is some simple content for this page.</p>\n    </body>\n</html>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RainShadow\eclipse-workspace\test0\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html parser')
  File "C:\Users\RainShadow\Desktop\PythonLibs\BeautifulSoup4\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

The code I ran to generate the above console output is below:

```
import requests 

page = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")
print(page.content)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

My question is where to best download a tree builder with the feature 'html parser'?

Answer (score 2):

Try this when initializing BS:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Note the period (`.`) there rather than a space. [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) ships out of the box with Python and should parse the page to the level you need. See [this documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for more info.

Comment: @SBF12345 No worries! Would you mind accepting my answer? Gotta get that sweet reputation :)

Comment: sure thing, but how do I go about 'accepting the answer'?  I'm still new to stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks usr2564301!